# Random vectors with the same distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I found the following question in my lecture notes on probability theory: suppose for some stochastic processes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ $\forall t_1,t_2$ $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})\overset{d}{=}(Y_{t_1}, Y_{t_2}).$ Does it imply $(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, X_{t_3})\overset{d}{=}(Y_{t_1}, Y_{t_2},Y_{t_3})\ \forall t_1,t_2,t_3?$

I'm positive it's false. I tried to construct some counterexample, using dependence/independence and coincidence of some components, dut didn't succeed. May be you can help me with some hints and ideas how to construct such counterexample. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $X_1,X_2,X_3$ pairwise independent but not mutually independent, and $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ mutually independent such that $Y_1$, resp. $Y_2$, resp. $Y_3$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, resp. $X_2$, resp. $X_3$.

If you want, complete the stochastic process with independent random variables $X_t,Y_t, t\notin\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: You mean $X_i \overset{d}{=} Y_i, i=1,2,3$?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.